# Maximum degree polynomial passing the points

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

What is the maximum degree polynomial passing the points below??
$$(0,2) (1,4) (2,8) (3,14) (4,22)$$

I guess the answer is 2 and the corresponding polynomial is $x^2+x+2$, but how can I prove that there is no polynomial of degree $3$ or $2$ passing these points?

Comment: Why do you think that there should be a maximum?

Comment: @YJT I am sorry, you are right. I confused this problem with the theorem that says there is a unique polynomial of degree n for n+1 points. I thought the degree has some limits, but I was wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $p$ is any polynomial passing through these points then $p(x)+x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)q(x)$ also passes through these points for any polynomial $q$. So there is no maximum value for the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.